# Saving thumb nail preview with JCrop, JQuery and asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jcrop

I've been dabbling with JCrop and I can get it working so far as uploading an image, selecting a region and then saving what I've selected to a cropped version of the original image. I can also get the thumbnail preview working, so that whatever I've selected (however big or small fits into a 150px*150px region)..so far all good.

The only problem I'm having now is saving what is in the thumbnail preview which is 150*150 and as mentioned contains whatever I have selected...

I've had a good look around on google and can't see anything to save the thumbmail preview..

Anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok bascially what I'm doing is saving the cropped image and then saving it again but resizing it to whatever dimensions are in the preview pane....I'm not sure it gives me the an exact replica of what's in the preview pane in terms of quality but it's not so bad I guess.